# Javascript problems when extending class

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, extend

I am facing some problems with extending classes on Javascript,
I have created a class that i want to extend then i have passed the call() method to call the parent but i am having an error, Could someone tell me how or what is the right way to extend and override a method?

**AbstractObject**

```
var AbstractObject= (function () {
    function AbstractObject() {
        var elements = {};
        var containerKey = null;
        var self = this;

        this.getElementByKey = function (key) {
            var object = elements[key];

            //if exist
            if (object.length == 1) {
                return object;
            }

            return null;
        };
        var __construct = function (that) {
            self.__construct();
        }(this);

    }

    AbstractObject.prototype = {
        __construct: function () {
            console.log('const');
        }
    };

    return AbstractObject;
})();
```

**Parent Class**

```
var Parent = (function () {
    function Parent() {
        AbstractObject.call(this);
    }

    Parent.prototype = {};

    return Parent;
})();
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: self.__construct is not a function [Learn More] AbstractObject.js
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: May I ask what this `__construct` thing is about at all? You really should simply omit it.

Comment: So you want `Parent` to inherit from `AbstractObject`? Then you need to use `Parent.prototype = Object.create(AbstractObject.prototype)`, otherwise there's no proper inheritance chain for `Parent` instances.

Comment: i want to override public construct on the parent because after that i will put many more functions to run on the private constructor.

Comment: A constructor never is really private. And if you want to overwrite initialisation stuff, that simply goes into the `function Parent() { … }` body.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, it helped me :D!